# gradlew.bat tasks FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: react-native

Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat tasks FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'E:\Project\Avesta\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\HP.gradle\caches\8.0.1\scripts\eawyea2vh1emg4hfiirosg1ux). > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64 * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 2s.

I tried to run npx react-native run-android and i get the above error. Please help with a fix.

I am expecting the npx react-native run-android to run the react app in my android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can following following steps for resolve this issue.

1. Check your JDK version: React Native currently recommends to use JDK 11. Make sure you have JDK 11 installed on your system.
2. Install JDK 11: If you don't have JDK 11 installed, download and install it using a package manager like Homebrew.
3. Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable: After installing JDK 11, update the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the JDK 11 installation directory.
4. Review React Native's Android development environment setup: Additionally, revisit the "Setting up the development environment" for Android section in the React Native documentation. Ensure that you have followed all the necessary steps to configure the Android development environment correctly.